# How to detect Ctrl+V in Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, user-interaction, copy-paste

What is the best way to detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in Silverlight?

I want to detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, to get access to the Clipboard.

Comment: Are you want to intercept globally in your application the Ctrl+V?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

To capture the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> keypress globally in your silverlight application, is fraught with difficulty. Events start at the child elements and bubble down to the parent controls, so simply handling KeyDown on your root UIElement will not work. Any text input control will first get the event and smother it (by setting Handled to true on the event args.) I think that if you use the DOM bridge and subscribe a handler to the browser KeyDown event for the silverlight element itself that you may actually be able to get to it first, and even handle it completely before any silverlight controls can. I think that would be the easiest way to intercept <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, but I have not tested it.

**Original Answer**

You should use the [System.Windows.Clipboard](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/11/25/silverlight-4-s-new-clipboard-support.aspx) class.

- GetText, which retrieves text from
  the clipboard
- SetText, which places
  text on the clipboard
- ContainsText,
  which indicates whether the clipboard
  currently contains text

Comment: The problem is not to get access to the clipboard, but to get access when the user uses the 'paste-function'.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (e.Key == Key.V)
{
    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        //do what you want on paste
    }
}
```

You have to use this on the keyUp event. More details can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189015%28VS.95%29.aspx